# textViewDidChange function not responding

Tags: swift, uitextview

I am trying to write Swift code to change the background color in my `UITextView` every time a user types any text. I have delegated my `UITextView` and added `textViewDidChange` as such:

```
extension DocumentViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let currentText = self.textView.text

        var seed = 0

        if currentText != self.textView.text {
            let myNum = seed%4
            let myColor = colorPicker(num: myNum)
            self.textView.backgroundColor = myColor
            seed += 1
        }
    }

    func colorPicker(num: Int) -> UIColor {
        let colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.purple]

        return colors[Int(num)]
    }

}
```

This code seems logical to me and Xcode isn't giving me any errors, however, when I run the program, I am not getting the desired results.

To test my function even further, I tried printing my variable `seed` and the value increments by 1. However, the value stays at 1 and doesn't continue incrementing everytime I type as I thought it would, and my output looks like this:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

I also tried adding `var seed = 0` inside my `DocumentViewController` class and changed my calls as `self.seed` within `textViewDidChange` as such:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

        let currentText = self.textView.text
        if currentText != self.textView.text {

            let myNum = self.seed % 4
            let myColor = colorPicker(num: myNum)
            self.textView.backgroundColor = myColor
            self.seed += 1
        }
    }
```

However the seed won't update or even print.

In conclusion, my textViewDidChange is not responding to any further changes. Any thoughts on what this issue could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control will never enter if as

```
if currentText != self.textView.text
```

is equal to

```
if self.textView.text != self.textView.text
```

which is false

//

Declare seed as an instance variable inside the class `DocumentViewController`

```
var seed = 0
var oldText = ""
```

//

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) { 

    if oldText != self.textView.text! {

       let myNum = seed%4
       let myColor = colorPicker(num: myNum)
       self.textView.backgroundColor = myColor
       seed += 1 
       oldText = self.textView.text!
   }
 }
```

//

One more thing to mention , if the user edits it then no need for oldText var , as the text will always hold a new change , if you set it from a server call that you don't know the content then leave it

Comment: I see the problem! So what would I need to add/change to enter the control? Because I am trying to change the background color any time any text is added to the UITextView